# Adding an empty line between the powerline/prompt line and the output line in ZSH?

Tags: command-line, zsh

I am using p10k, and I haven't seen any option other than

```
  # Add an empty line before each prompt.
  typeset -g POWERLEVEL9K_PROMPT_ADD_NEWLINE=true
```

which that adds a line before the powerline/prompt line. An in-depth search hasn't produced any results. How can I add an empty line between the powerline/prompt line and the output line in ZSH?

Answer (score 0):

Put `\n` at the beginning of environment variable PS1.

PS1 is the command prompt variable.

For example:

`export PS1="\n$PS1"`

Comment: Nothing changed. I also tried adding it at the end ```export PS1="$PS1\n".

Comment: @Centaro maybe zsh uses other env variable for command prompt. Try `$PROMPT`.

Comment: I tried ```export PROMPT="$PROMPT\n"``` and ```export PROMPT="\n$PROMPT"```, but to no avail.

Comment: @Centaro strange env you have there then.